# substitute strings in a nested list in commonlisp

Tags: common-lisp, substitution, clisp

I have nested list (("H" "E" "L" "L" "O") ("T" "H" "I" "S") ("I" "S") ("A") ("T" "E" "S" "T")) I want to substitute each string in the list to another string using substitute but it does not work my code is:

```
(substitute "H" "W" paragraph)
```

paragraph is the name of the nested list.

Comment: Use the `SUBST` function with an appropriate `:TEST` function.

Comment: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_substc.htm

Comment: it didn't work again :( will you please modify the one line of code that i have written on the top it did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Use [`SUBST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_substc.htm):

```
(setq new-list (subst "W" "H" old-list :test #'string=))
```

If you need to modify the list in place, use `NSUBST` and assign the result back to the original variable:

```
(setq old-list (nsubst "W" "H" old-list :test #'string=))
```

Comment: Always use the return value also of `nsubst`, do not rely on the argument having been modified correctly.  `Nsubst` is not for modifying in place but for avoiding consing.  This may have the desired effect in many implementations, but, quoting the spec: _the original tree is modified and returned as the function result, but the result may not be eq to tree_.